# Calling a controllers method in another controller Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-controllers

I am using Ember's Need Api to call a method of a controller in another controller. I am able to get the instance of the controller but when I am calling it method it returns me this error    `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method.`

This is how I am calling it:

```
Cards.CardsIndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: 'account_info',
     actions: {
        accountInfoStart:function(){
               console.log(this.get('controllers.account_info').test()); // error here


        }
    }
});
```

This is the controller whose function I want to call

```
Cards.AccountInfoController = Ember.Controller.extend({


    actions:{

        test: function(){

            alert(1);
        }

    }

});
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`test` is not technically a method, but an action or event. Use the `send` method instead:

```
this.get('controllers.account_info').send('test', arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: For people who need it to work with nested folders, here's a solution for it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29269015/499700

Answer (score 5):

As per Ember documentation; create a property that lazily looks up another controller in the container. This can only be used when defining another controller.

legacy ember application example:

```
App.PostController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  accountInfo: Ember.inject.controller()

  this.get('accountInfo').send('test')
});
```

modern ember application example:

```
// in an ember app created with ember-cli
// below snippet would be the app/controllers/post.js file
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appController: Ember.inject.controller('application')
});
```

You can find more [documentation about Ember.inject here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller)

Comment: For users cruising the web, this answer is most accurate for applications running  Ember 2.x and above.

Answer (score 2):

From the Updated Ember Documentation :

```
import { inject } from '@ember/controller';
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appController: inject('application')
});
```

For further reference, you can find out by this link  [https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/#toc_ad-hoc-injections](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/dependency-injection/)